# how to get all values of a patricular metrics in sonar REST api

Tags: web-services, rest, sonarqube

I was able to get the list of projects(resources) from sonar REST API using the following java code

```
Sonar sonar = Sonar.create("wwww.example.com/sonar/api/resources?metrics=nloc");
ResourceQuery query = new ResourceQuery();
List resourceList = sonar.findAll(query);
for(Resource resource : resourceList){
  System.out.println(resource.getid()+":"+resource.getMetricIntValue("nloc"));
}
```

But this resulted in

```
1001:null
1002:null
1003:null
1004:null
```

Why is the lines of code value returning null?

Comment: Is there any way get the total count of the Major Issues for a project? http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?createdAfter='${timestap}'&pageSize=10000&severities=BLOCKER,CRITICAL,MAJOR gives list of issues but not the count and response is limited to 500..

Answer (score 5):

The [docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions) show the `metrics` parameter with a value of `ncloc`, not `nloc`. I think you've just got a typo.